# Laravel form request validation add errors to the MessageBag without using the after hook

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Why does adding errors to the errors array, outside the after hook of the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` Object in Laravel, doesn't trigger the `ValidationException` exception?

Let's assume I am validating a phoneNumber field from a request with the `withValidator` method in a form request class. When i add an error to the errors array directly without using the after callback on the validator, the error isn't considered but when i pass it inside the after hook callback the error is recognised. So can someone please explain to me the why because i thought since the errors method is on the Validator object it would be straight forward appended to the errors.

**Here the scenario without the after hook: This doesn't work as expected**

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    if($validator->fails()){
       return; 
    }
    
    $phoneNumber = $validator->validated()["phoneNumber"];

    if(strlen($phoneNumber) != 10){
        $validator->errors()->add("phoneNumber","Invalid phone number");
    }

}
```

**And here is the one with the after hook: This works as expected**

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    if($validator->fails()){
       return; 
    }

    $validator->after(function (Validator $validator) {

        $phoneNumber = $validator->validated()["phoneNumber"];

        if(strlen($phoneNumber) != 10){
            $validator->errors()->add("phoneNumber","Invalid phone number");
        }
    });

}
```

Most of the articles i read don't tell why we must use the after hook they just put it there so i would like to understand what's the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [this chapter](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#after-validation-hook) of the Laravel documentation on validation, you can see that you're supposed to check `if ($validator->fails())` **after** defining your `$validator->after()` callback.

From what I understand, the `$validator->after()` method only *registers* a callback to be executed after the validation is triggered.

The validation actually happens when you call `$validator->validated()` or `$validator->fails()`. In your case, you're either calling the `fails` method *before* registering your callback (so it won't be executed) or calling the `validated` method *within* the callback.

I suggest you register your callback **first** with `$validator->after()` and only then should you use `$validator->fails()` and/or `$validator->validated()` to execute the validation.

```
public function withValidator(Validator $validator)
{
    // No need to check ->failed() because ->validated() automatically
    // returns a response to the user if the validation fails.

    $validator->after(function (Validator $validator)
    {
        // Add your custom validation rules here...
        if (strlen($phoneNumber) !== 10)
        {
            $validator->errors()->add('phoneNumber', 'Invalid phone number');
        }
    });

    // Valdidate the data.
    // This line will automatically return a response
    // to the user if the validation fails.
    $validated = $validator->validated();

    // Retrieve the phone number
    $phoneNumber = $validated['phoneNumber'];

    // Use the validated $phoneNumber here...
}
```

Comment: Has anyone tested this code? Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense and fills in where the documentation stops. I will be writing an algorithm based on this answer, and if it works, I will report. Upvoting anyway...